# Android Status Bar Prevent Coloring

Tags: android, colors, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar

I am having a problem preventing the status bar from taking on the primaryColor.  I want to leave the status bar unstyled but on lollipop it is always taking on the color of the primaryColor defined in my styles.xml

Excerpt from styles:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>


<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- START Market Themes -->

<style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColorBlue</item>
</style>
```

styles/v21

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/toolbar_elevation</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to be your primary colour.
The status bar gets its colour form your `colorPrimaryDark` so change

`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimary</item>`

to

```
<item name="colorPrimary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
```

I think this should only be necessary in your styles-v21 but I'm not close enough to anything to test it.

[Docs here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

> ```
> <resources>
>   <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
>   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
>     <!-- Main theme colors -->
>     <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
>     <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
>     <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
>     <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
>     <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
>     <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
>   </style>
> </resources>
> ```